# DevDemon Subscriptions CARD_CREATE: User authentication failed

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

No matter what I do I keep getting the following error when trying to subscribe to a plan:

```
CARD_CREATE: User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.
```

I'm logged in as a user I have set up as "Test" account in the settings.

I have regenerated a brand new Authorize.net transaction key with no affect. I know for sure my login id is correct as I'm using it on multiple other sites/systems.

Is there something I need to enable for Subscriptions to work!?

***EDIT**: As it stands I've created a Sandbox Authorize.net account and all systems are a go with it. So I'm assuming I need to set something up in my actuall Authorize account. I did notice Subscriptios is using CIM and all my other systems use AIM. Is there something there I need to do?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm getting the same message, but using Stripe

Comment: It was an issue with our Authorize.NET account. We used different credentials and it lit up. Sorry I don't have a better solution for you as we still don't know what the difference was.